# MVC3 Auth returnURL

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I using Forms authentication in MVC3. The `returnUrl` seems to be duplicating the part of the url for some reason. For example:

http://localhost/customer/?filter=1&sort=3

becomes:

returnUrl=/localhost/customer/?filter=1&sort=3&filter=1&sort=3

As you can see the additional parameters are being duplicated for some reason. Anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be worth watching the `returnUrl` as it passes through the system. At some point, something is adding the second set of parameters on the end. Could it be that those parameters are being added to the end of the current URL, where the current URL has the `?returnUrl=` parameter already on? If this is the case, it may be worth ensuring that the `returnUrl` is encoded. e.g. `Url.Encode(returnUrl)` before sticking it on the end.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it working you have to do the following:

1. Imagine that this is an Event Page where user have to login

`In order to subscribe for the event you have to < a style=" background-color:Black; color:White; font-weight:bold;" href="@Url.Content("~/Account/Login?returnUrl=/Events/Index")">Login< /a> or create a New Account.`

1. public ActionResult Login(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
   {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
       if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
       {
          MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);

   ```
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

      if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
       && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
     {
                   return Redirect(returnUrl);
     }
     else
     {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
     }
           }
           else
           {
               ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
           }
       }

       return View(model);
   ```

   }